# il8n not working in react app after converting to single spa

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-spa

After converting a react app to single spa  which had il8n implemented I am facing a problem where translation.json cannot be accessed hence not fetching the labels.

Should I modify something in the webpack.config.js to get it right

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import i18nextHttpBackend from "i18next-http-backend";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";


i18n
  .use(i18nextHttpBackend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    lng: Cookies.get("locale") || "es",
    fallbackLng: "en",
    debug: false,
    supportedLngs: ["en", "es"],
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },

  });



export default i18n;
```

il8n is imported in App.js
import "./i18n";

Initially before converting to single spa the app was working fine and making a call to
http://localhost:3000/locales/en/translation.json
but after converting the app to single spa the get request would fail.
http://single-spa-playground.org/locales/en/translation.json

I did follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8oaySHuj3Y&list=PLLUD8RtHvsAOhtHnyGx57EYXoaNsxGrTU&index=13 to convert the react app to single spa.

WebPack Config

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const singleSpaDefaults = require("webpack-config-single-spa-react");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => {
  console.log(webpackConfigEnv);
  const defaultConfig = singleSpaDefaults({
    orgName: "WHATEVR",
    projectName: "WHATEVER",
    webpackConfigEnv,
    argv,
  });

  return merge(defaultConfig, {
    // modify the webpack config however you'd like to by adding to this object
    plugins: [new Dotenv()],
    devServer: {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":
          "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
          "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization",
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Tried Solution but still not solved
[Reactjs - error loading translation files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576842/reactjs-error-loading-translation-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that previously, the React app also served as the server that provided the index.html file along with other static assets (eg. your localized translation json files). In single-spa, that is no longer the case; that is instead now the root-config. You'll need to update your [i18next-http-backend `loadPath` configuration](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend#backend-options) so that the library tries to retrieve them from the right path which is no longer the root url. Without being familiar with what you want to achieve, you have two options:

- use `__webpack_public_path__` to dynamically create the correct URL to point to the assets served by this microfrontend, eg. `` loadPath: `${__webpack_public_path__} /locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json`, ``
- if you have a separate i18n service, point the URL to that. This may also require `crossDomain` and `withCredentials` depending on how that is also configured.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @filoxo was very helpful. What didn't help me though was the fact that we needed a public folder outside of `src`. When deploying my app to s3, it would never add the translation files.
So I moved the locales inside src and used webpack copy plugin to move the file into the dist folder. So setup-wise this looks like this:

Webpack config:

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

plugins: [
  new CopyPlugin({
    patterns: [
      { from: 'src/assets/locales', to: 'locales' }
    ]
  })
]
```

i18n Settings:

```
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    supportedLngs: ['en', 'de'],
    backend: {
      loadPath: `${__webpack_public_path__}locales/{{lng}}-translation.json`
    }
  });
```

Hope this helps someone who was like me trying to figure out why it wouldn't load the translations.